# Parsing JSON with Sencha Touch 2 MVC not working

Tags: json, parsing, model-view-controller, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to parse a JSON file and display different values using a `sliderfield.drag()` method, but for some reason it's not working. I am not even getting a value on the console.log. What is missing?

## app/model/agenda.json

```
{
 "agenda":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Ed Spencer",
            "email": "ed@sencha.com"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Abe Elias",
            "email": "abe@sencha.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

## app/model/Contact.js

```
Ext.define('Test.model.Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'agenda.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'agenda'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

## app/controller/Settings.js

```
Ext.define('Test.controller.Settings', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: ['Test.model.Agenda'], 
    config: {
        refs: {
        },
        control: {
            'mainview sliderfield[action=updateSurface]': {
                drag: 'updateSurface' 
            },
        }
    },
    updateSurface: function(me){
        var value = me.get('value');

        var yields = Ext.create('Test.model.Contact');
        console.log(yields);
        yields.load({
            success: function(){
                console.log(yields.getName());
            }        
        });    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I practically solve this problem using JavaScript instead of SenchaTouch Models.

## app/listener/Agenda.js

```
Ext.define('Test.listener.Agenda', {

    parse: function(){

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", "resources/json/agenda.json", false);

        request.send(null);
        var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);

        return data.agenda[0].name;
    },
});
```

## app/controller/Settings.js

```
Ext.define('Test.controller.Settings', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: ['Test.listener.Agenda'], 
    config: {
        refs: {
        },
        control: {
            'mainview sliderfield[action=updateSurface]': {
                drag: 'updateSurface' 
            },
        }
    },
    updateSurface: function(me){
        var agenda = new Test.listener.Agenda();
        console.log(agenda);               
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your code:

```
yield.load({...});
```

`yield` is a reserved word in JavaScript. You probably meant to say

```
yields.load({...});
```